How to control a stepper motor using an absolute position sensor which has an error band?
I am using Feather M4 express development board with DC Motor + Stepper FeatherWing and Ethernet FeatherWing stacked on it. The idea is to read the target position from the UDP from 0 t0 360 degrees and control the steps of the stepper motor by reading the current encoder values. I am using this library for reading the encoder values.
The encoder is mounted at an angle of 90 degrees to the starting motor position. I am currently able to read the encoder values but even with the moving average filter, there seems to be inaccurate values sent on the SSI frequently along with the correct values. Since the targetPosition is not stable in spite of the moving average filter, the stepper keeps rotating until it finds the defined targetPosition (which should be 0 or offset of -90 degrees). However, defining the initial targetPosition = 10 seems to bring it to the stable position every time after 2-4 full rotations.
The next issue is, when I send the required angle on the UDP message, the stepsToMove in the moveToPosition() function seems to be the right value, but the stepper just does not move the required number of steps. When the currentPosition < targetPosition, most of the times, the stepper just keeps moving and in effect, blocking the microcontroller.
I am looking for improvements in the software as the hardware cannot be changed.

How can I improve the filter values to get the most accurate encoder values?
How can I add this offset to the rotateToIntialPosition() function and to move it dynamically combined with this offset during the operation in the moveToPosition() function?
Since the encoder is is expected to have an error band, how can I include the +/- 5 degrees in the control loop in the moveToPosition() function?


also posted at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/719639/how-to-read-position-sensor-values-more-accurately-for-stpper-control

This may not be your only issue, but you have a problem with the
function getFilteredEncoderAngle() which is... plain wrong. Imagine
your motor is exactly at angle 0 but, due to noise, you get half of the
readings reporting 0.5°, and the other half at 359.5°. This is a pretty
small amount of noise, with only 0.5° amplitude. The average, of course,
should be zero, but your filter will report 180°: it would be impossible
to get a result that is more wrong than that.
I expect this to wreak havoc on your program every time you cross the
zero angle. Your motor could cross it smoothly as 358° → 359° → 0° → 1°…
but your filter will believe the motor is suddenly spinning very fast in
the opposite direction.
You really need a smoothing filter that is aware that angles are
supposed to wrap at 360°. I have written an answer a few years ago
showing three different ways to implement a wrap-aware smoothing
filter. Rob Tillaart has taken my third approach (my favorite) and
implemented it in the Arduino library runningAngle. Note that this
is not a “plain” running average, but rather an exponentially-weighted
running average.

thanks for the suggestion. I only want to read the absolute position from the encoder and move my stepper to the required position. I am still having a hard time implementing the runningAngle library. I understand the filtered value function is a bad idea. I just want to use the moveToPosition(target_steps) function. What would be your suggestion for this?

@dreamcoder: I don't understand your question. You don't need to implement the runningAngle library, as it has already been implemented by Rob Tillaart. You can install it from the Arduino library manager. For using it, look at the Usage section of the README. You can also look at the example sketch named also “runningAngle”.

I have used the runningAngle library in my sketch and it only makes a marginal improvement. The position sensing encoder still reads half of the values wrong. Which makes the stepper control deviate quite a lot. Is there a way to filter out the wrong values and use only the valid ones?
